# Reinstallation failures

Tags: boot

I had 16.04 LTS installed, but something filled up all 1.7 terabyte HD and could not delete or empty trash. Now, after entering password, no response and desktop icons gone. Attempted to reinstall new system using new DVD iso installation. Boots initially to CD (light blinks), but then seems to go to HD system because I end up with previous desktop and password which gives no response as HD boot. How do I get a new installation to work? Bios is set to DVD boot. I can not get terminal session on any attempt.
Thanks.